# Python round() too slow, faster way to reduce precision?

Tags: python

I am doing the following:

```
TOLERANCE = 13
some_float = ...
round(some_float, TOLERANCE)
```

This is run many times, so performance is important. I have to round some_float due to floating point representation error. I don't actually need to "round" the number in that sense, just remove digits after 13 trailing digits.

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: How do you know it is too slow?

Comment: The above code is run millions of times, the extra work required to run round() reduces performance significantly.

Comment: You can add all the floats to a numpy array and do a vectorized round.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've made some benches to compare `round(some_float, TOLERANCE)` with `int(some_float * p + 0.5)/p` (with p as `10**TOLERANCE)` and here are the results:

- round: 6.20 seconds
- int divide+multiply: 3.53

my bench:

```
import time


TOLERANCE = 5
some_float = 12.2439924563634564564564
nb_loops = 10000000

start_time = time.time()
for _ in range(nb_loops):
    r1 = round(some_float, TOLERANCE)
print(r1,time.time()-start_time)

start_time = time.time()
p = float(10**TOLERANCE)
for _ in range(nb_loops):
    r2 = int(some_float * p + 0.5)/p
print(r2,time.time()-start_time)
```

result:

```
12.24399 6.208600997924805
12.24399 3.525486946105957
```

so the `int` solution is faster. `round` is probably better at handling the rounding of negative numbers (as someone commented, it makes a lot extra calls, so the code is more complex). The rounding may be different depending on the sign of the input number. Accuracy vs raw speed, again.

Add `0.5` or not to round or truncate. This seems to be a detail for you, but the `int` solution (provided that `10**TOLERANCE` is precomputed) seems faster.

If you want to use that technique, you could be tempted to put the rounding code in a function:

```
TOLERANCE = 5
p = float(10**TOLERANCE)
def my_round_5(some_float):
    return int(some_float * p + 0.5)/p
```

and call it like this:

```
r2 = my_round(some_float)
```

that would be still faster than `round`, but a tad slower than using the formula inline (because function call isn't free)

note that I've used `p = float(10**TOLERANCE)` and not `p = 10**TOLERANCE` so the code is compatible with python 2 (else it would truncate the decimal part due to integer division)

Comment: check the comments of the question, perhaps include the numpy approach to your benchmark?

Comment: @Kraay89 I could but I feel that would steal the idea to the one who got it. Why not another complementary answer? (it may not be possible to compute the values in //, maybe the algorithm is sequential and it's not possible, otherwise, good idea)

Comment: Thanks, this is a lot faster! The actual float I am truncating is the following calculation: (B.x - A.x) * (C.y - A.y) - (B.y - A.y) * (C.x - A.x). Ill look at numpy as well, see if theres an even faster way.

Comment: How come your implemented `round` is faster than the standard one? Why wouldn't they implement it as you do?

Comment: @BartFriederichs If you look at the round() implementation in cpython, you'll see that there are quite a few function calls (fabs(), floor(), copysign()). So its slower because there are more operations to execute.

Comment: @TaipanRex I saw that, just makes you wonder why the C implementation needs that much more code.

Comment: @BartFriederichs I was as much surprised as you were :) I'm running python 3.4. Maybe there's a catch with negative numbers to choose which last digit to display, though... If you don't care, then my implementation is enough. speed vs accuracy again.

Comment: https://github.com/TaipanRex/pyvisgraph This is the project that I'm using the code for. There are several other functions where I have done my own implementations because its faster than using the built in ones. When you are running something millions of times, small things like cutting down function calls help.

Comment: My 0.02$ but the multiply and divide does not handle Nan when the round() function in python or numpy.round() does.

Answer (score 5):

Using `int`, multiply and divide is faster. You can use `timeit` with `ipython` in order to quickly benchmark Python code.

```
In [7]: %timeit int(1.12345678901234*(10**13))/(10.**13)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 380 ns per loop

In [8]: %timeit round(1.12345678901234, 13)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.32 µs per loop
```