# Fastest way to round random numbers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, rounding

I want to generate random numbers up to certain precision, one at a time (so I am not looking for a vectorized solution).

I found a method in [this QnA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44920655/) on stackoverflow, and it gave me these benchmarks as promised. The method is definitely is almost twice as fast.
Now, here's what is puzzling me.

```
%timeit int(0.5192853551955484*(10**5)+0.5)/(10.**5)      #> 149 ns ± 5.76 ns per loop 
%timeit round(0.5192853551955484, 5)                      #> 432 ns ± 11.7 ns per loop
## Faster as expected

fl = random.random()
pr = 5
%timeit int(fl*(10**pr)+0.5)/(10.**pr)                    #> 613 ns ± 27.9 ns per loop 
%timeit round(fl, pr)                                     #> 444 ns ± 9.25 ns per loop
## Slower?!

%timeit int(random.random()*(10**5)+0.5)/(10.**5)         #> 280 ns ± 29.3 ns per loop 
%timeit round(random.random(), 5)                         #> 538 ns ± 17.5 ns per loop
## Faster than using a variable even though it has the overhead
## of creating a random number for each call?
```

Why is the above method slower when I'm using variables? It regains the lost speed when I pass the randomly generated number directly.
What am I missing?

In my code, since I require rounding at multiple places, I would like it wrapped in a function as follows. I understand that there is a small cost associated with the function call, but I don't think that's whats costing the bulk of the increased time. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44920965/5526060) says, it still ought to be faster than the standard `round()` function of python.

```
def rounder(fl, pr):
    p = float(10**pr)
    return int(fl * p + 0.5)/p

%timeit rounder(random.random(), 5)                       #> 707 ns ± 14.2 ns per loop 
%timeit round(random.random(), 5)                         #> 525 ns ± 22.1 ns per loop

## Having a global variable does make it faster by not having to do the 10**5 everytime
p = float(10**5)
def my_round_5(fl):
    return int(fl* p + 0.5)/p

%timeit my_round_5(random.random())                       #> 369 ns ± 18.9 ns per loop
```

I would prefer not having a global variable in my code, but let's say I concede to this requirement, but the performance gain is smaller, than using the formula without variables.

**So, the final question would be, which method would be most beneficial for me to use?**
There is only a gain of 100-150ns to switching to a function that requires a global variable. Or is there someway that can be faster.

Comment: Well the `rounder` function you have put is not the *exactly* same as the one described in the link you provided...

Comment: @DaniMesejo Hi Dani, Sorry I missed one subtlety. I have made it the same now, but the problem still persists.

Comment: could you use a generator?  i.e. something that `yield`s a single value every time, that would be a nice place to put the precalculation of `p`

Comment: @SamMason That actually sounds like a good way to solve the problem.  I'll try it. Can you add the code for it and benchmark it against the above method and add it to your solution. Then your's would be a complete answer to my question, so I can mark it and move on, hopefully. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Python byte-compiler "knows" how numbers work, and it uses this knowledge to optimise things where it can.  You can use the `dis` module to see what's happening.

For example, your first "fast" example:

```
from dis import dis

def fn():
    return int(0.5192853551955484*(10**5)+0.5)/(10.**5)

dis(fn)
```

actually does:

```
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (int)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (51929.03551955484)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (100000.0)
              8 BINARY_TRUE_DIVIDE
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

i.e. it knows what `0.5192853551955484*(10**5)+0.5` evaluates to and does it when compiling the byte code.  If you have `pr` as a parameter it can't do that, so has to do more work when running the code.

To answer the "what would be best" question, maybe something like:

```
def fn(pr):
     # cache to prevent global lookup
     rng = random.random
     # evaluate precision once
     p = 10. ** pr
     # generate infinite stream of random numbers
     while True:
         yield int(rng() * p + 0.5) / p
```

can be benchmarked with:

```
x = fn(5)
%timeit next(x)
```

giving ~160ns per loop, while:

```
%timeit int(fl*(10**pr)+0.5)/(10**pr)
%timeit int(fl*(10.**pr)+0.5)/(10.**pr)
```

run in ~500 and ~250ns.  Didn't realise that int vs float exponentiation was so different!

Comment: I see. So it is caching the value after the first call?

Comment: before the first call!  the Python interpreter only evaluates "bytecode", it's the process of turning source code into bytecode does the optimisation

Comment: Okay. I wasn't aware of this, or the `dis` module. This will be handy moving forward. Thanks!

Comment: Wow. Float exponentiation does seem to help with reducing the time taken for the remaining calculations. Learning new small things everyday. :D

Comment: One more questions regarding `rng = random.random`. `# cache to prevent global lookup`, does this mean that this random number generator is a local one, having a different seed from other `random.random()` calls I may have in my code?
If I replaced `rng()` with `random.random()`, what implications does this have?

Comment: nope, just caching the function lookup. it's just that local variables are (slightly) quicker to access than global variables.  when you use `random.random()` you do three things, 1. lookup the `random` module, 2. lookup the `random` function, 3. invoke the function (see `dis` output).  we're just caching the first two steps into a (faster) local variable.  it's faster because local variables are just an integer index, rather than the hash lookup used for global variables